# how to pass a selected value from a filter to a dax measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a slicer and a measure. the measure value used to be constant but right now I want to change the value based on the selection. my old query is

```
Weight Total Acceptance = 
var lk=IF(
    'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] >0.85,
    "5",
    IF(
        'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] > 0.7 && 'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.85,
        "3",
        If('Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.7,"1"
    )))
    Return lk*0.5
```

I have another datatable that I created to hold the slicers value.

```
Group Name
DG
KL
```

What I want is pass the value(DG or KL) to my measure. something like this

If selectedvalue=DG then execute the below

```
Weight Total Acceptance = 
    var lk=IF(
        'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] >0.85,
        "5",
        IF(
            'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] > 0.7 && 'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.85,
            "3",
            If('Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.7,"1"
        )))
        Return lk*0.5
```

If Selectedvalue=KL then, execute the below

```
Weight Total Acceptance = 
    var lk=IF(
        'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] >0.70,
        "8",
        IF(
            'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] > 0.5 && 'Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.70,
            "3",
            If('Sprints'[Measure Current Accepted Point %] <0.5,"1"
        )))
        Return lk*0.3
```

Comment: Why just don't use SELECTEDVALUE function to check what is selected? https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/

Comment: Thank you. I have used selectedvalue and a couple of variables and it worked.